# Replacing connected regions by their skeleton

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, morphological-analysis, mathematical-morphology

[image: Binary Medical Image with some connected regions]

Here I show a binary Image having many connected regions(white). I want to replace these regions by single pixel edges. how can I do it?

please help someone

I want [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCabp.jpg) type of result

Comment: How about changing any white pixels to black pixels where the white pixel is surrounded by other white pixels?

Comment: @VaughnCato - but it will give double edges, am I right?

Comment: Take for example a 3x3 square of white pixels.  The middle pixel would have white pixels on all sides, so it would be turned to black.  The other ones would be unaffected, leaving you with a one pixel border.

Comment: @VaughnCato I mean when I do it , it will just draw a boundary for connected regions right? actually I want to draw a line through the center of the body, not around it.

Comment: Yes, it will give you a one pixel boundary around the edges.  That sounded like what you wanted.  If that isn't what you want, could you give an example of the result you want for a simple case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BWMORPH](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) with the `skel` option finds the skeleton of the image. Note that I needed to clean up the image a little bit to get a decent result

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Paok.jpg');
img = imopen(img,strel('disk',3)); %# you may want to play with the radius here
border = bwmorph(img,'skel',inf);
```

[image]

Comment: @crack_addict: I've modified my answer so that you'll get the skeleton.